# SemanticException [Error 10025]: Line 1:7 Expression not in GROUP BY key 'stock_symbol'

Tags: hive, hiveql

This is my Hive query:

```
select a.stock_symbol,a.stock_date,a.stock_price_open,a.stock_price_high,
       a.stock_price_low,a.stock_price_close,b.stock_symbol,
       MAX(b.stock_price_high), 
       MIN(b.stock_price_low) 
from YAHOO_STOCKS a
join YAHOO_STOCKS b
on  a.stock_symbol=b.stock_symbol
where b.stock_symbol=a.stock_symbol
   and b.stock_date > date_sub(a.stock_date,364)
   and b.stock_date <= a.stock_date
group by b.stock_symbol
order by a.stock_symbol,a.stock_date;
```

I am getting this error:

> FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10025]: Line 1:7 Expression not in GROUP BY key 'stock_symbol'

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you use UDF , you have to group by all other columns.

Use this query:

```
select a.stock_symbol,a.stock_date,a.stock_price_open,a.stock_price_high,
       a.stock_price_low,a.stock_price_close,b.stock_symbol,
       MAX(b.stock_price_high), 
       MIN(b.stock_price_low) 
from YAHOO_STOCKS a
join YAHOO_STOCKS b
on  a.stock_symbol=b.stock_symbol
where b.stock_date > date_sub(a.stock_date,364)
   and b.stock_date <= a.stock_date
group by a.stock_symbol,a.stock_date,a.stock_price_open,a.stock_price_high,
       a.stock_price_low,a.stock_price_close,b.stock_symbol
order by a.stock_symbol,a.stock_date;
```

Comment: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10004]: Line 12:9 Invalid table alias or column reference 'a': (possible column names are: stock_symbol, stock_date, stock_price_open, stock_price_high, stock_price_low, stock_price_close, _c7, _c8)..........................

the schema of table is 
exchange,stock_symbol,date,open,high,low,close,volume,adj close

even i have tried selecting all columns of my table in SELECT query as wella s GROUP BY query but of no use

Comment: Can you post your 'Create Table YAHOO_STOCKS ...' query.

Comment: CREATE TABLE  YAHOO_STOCKS (exchange String,stock_symbol String,stock_date String,stock_price_open double, stock_price_high double, stock_price_low double, stock_price_close double, stock_volume double, stock_price_adj_close double) 
ROW format DELIMITED 
Fields TERMINATED by ','
STORED as textfile;

Comment: 'EXCHANGE' is a reserved keyword. Are you able to create table with this?? You can not use it as a Column name.

Comment: Sorry for above comment . You can do that with the help of ` operator.

Comment: There is no exception when  I am running the query. Are you making any changes?? Copy and paste the same code which I wrote. It is running fine on my machine. Please let me know if you still face any problem.

Comment: no, im not changing any code, even i drop the previous table and created new one in which i used (`) before exchange, and i load the data, & finally copy paste the query you have  posted here, but still same exception........FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10004]: Line 12:9 Invalid table alias or column reference 'a': (possible column names are: stock_symbol, stock_date, stock_price_open, stock_price_high, stock_price_low, stock_price_close, _c7, _c8)

Comment: Hey finally solved it. The root of the problem is alias vs qualified alias which i came to know from stack overflow user gordon linoff's answer to a user which i found while googling the exception i got.Yours answer is right,only thing have to change is the order by clause... instead of " order by a.stock_symbol,a.stock_date;" use "order by stock_symbol,stock_date". very much obliged for your reply and time RAMIT.